# Link Identity pool and user pool using AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a hybrid mobile app uses the AWS Javascript SDK to integrate with Amazon Cognito, using a Cognito user pool as the Identity Provider. It works.

I need to traverse the data using the AWS API to produce a report. A key part is listing which user (showing their username) is associated with which items (associated with their Cognito identity).

### The Problem

I have a list of Cognito Identities from [`ListIdentities`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-identity-2014-06-30.html#listidentities). I have a list of users in the Cognito User Pool from [`ListUsers`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#listusers). What links the Identity to the User?

### I've tried...

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965465/119750) says the User's `sub` field is their IdentityId. Iterating through, no subs match any IdentityId values.

I thought the answer was in Cognito Identity's [`DescribeIdentity`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-identity-2014-06-30.html#describeidentity). This returns a map of `Logins` - which I expected to be an array of User IDs associated with this Identity. However it returns a map containing 1 URL (the URL of my User pool), which doesn't map to the user.

```
["Logins"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(55) "cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_*********"
}
```

How can I navigate the API from the Identity to the user, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as i know there is no easy way to do this. You can keep and maintain associations in a separate data store like DynamoDB.