# Which parameter can be used as primary key from AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, cloud, amazon-cognito

I read some questions and answers about my issue, but I still don't know the answer.

[Can I use the userSub in AWS Cognito as primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430339/can-i-use-the-usersub-in-aws-cognito-as-primary-key)

[AWS Cognito: Difference between Cognito ID and sub, what should I use as primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645932/aws-cognito-difference-between-cognito-id-and-sub-what-should-i-use-as-primary)

First, I will try to describe my case.

I want to create an application with spring boot as a resource server that uses oauth2. Then to save me some time with user management, I was hoping to use AWS Cognito since it allows me to create users as admin. I can set it up that it won't let other people sign up for themselves, which is crucial for me since my app will have restricted access; the admin will manage that.

Now to my question, which field of AWS Cognito can I use as the primary key for keeping user-specific data in my DB? I read that neither `username`nor `sub` is correct.
`username` can be changed, for example, and `sub` is globally unique, so it can't be restored. Is there any way to create a custom field where AWS Cognito will autogenerate UUID that I can use, and if I had to restore the user pool, I would have an option to set this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still go with username. If it is ever changed, just update your database to reflect this change.
You can also create a custom attributes in user pool. You can use that to store a self generated id. As for automatically generating this, you can have a [post confirmation lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html) that will use [adminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) to assign a unique id.

Comment: Thank you for your response, for now I went with keycloak, but I will use AWS Cognito eventually and this autogeneration will be needed. With this feature I could use this autogenerated field as primary key.